# Value of variable '@{credentials}[0]' is not list or list-like

Tags: list, variables, robotframework

I am an  new robotframework user, when I try to use list variable, I got below error. Really don't where am I wrong?

```
Value of variable '@{credentials}[0]' is not list or list-like.

@{credentials}    Admin    admin123
Input Text    id=txtUsername    @{credentials}[0]
```

Comment: The code you posted can't run as posted. Please [edit]  your question to include a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Robot Framework 3.1, the format to access list items was `@{credentials}[0]`. In current version, the format is `${credentials}[0]`.

Format `@{credentials}[0]` can only be used on a list of lists (meaning the final result is a list).

See the documentation: [Accessing list and dictionary items](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#accessing-list-and-dictionary-items)

Answer (score 2):

```
'@{credentials}[0]' is not list or list-like.

@{credentials}    Admin    admin123 Input Text    id=txtUsername   
@{credentials}[0]
```

This is a list in robot framework. To extract
`Admin` we can use `${credentials}[0]`. You get the error because your
framework version is higher but you refer to the old content. It is resolved by using `${credentials}[0]`. For more clarity,
you can refer to this:
https://robocorp.com/docs/languages-and-frameworks/robot-framework/variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your code format is right in your question.
But I guess your code is like below:

```
*** Variables ***
    @{credentials}    Admin    admin123

*** Test Cases ***
    Create List Variable
    Log    @{credentials}[0]
```

If you want to input `Admin` to `id-txtUsername`, You need change like this:

```
Input Text    id=txtUsername    ${credentials}[0]
```

I think you need to read this [section](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable-syntax) to figure out how `@` sign works.
With `@` sign, the list is expanded and individual items.

Example from User Guide. Both Testcase is the same:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Constants
    Login    robot    secret

List Variable
    Login    @{USER}
```