# issue with loging a list and list element in robot frame work

Tags: variables, robotframework

i want to log a list in robot frame work

i tried LOG @{listname} but it throws an error

to acccess the list element i use LOG @{listname}[0] it also throws an error

LOG @{listname} -- print list to log
LOG @{listname}[0] -- print the first element to log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value of variable '@{credentials}\[0\]' is not list or list-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748785/value-of-variable-credentials0-is-not-list-or-list-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Log%20List
There is Log List to log all the values in List. Please see the below example

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
@{NUMBERS}       ${1}    ${2}    ${5}
@{NAMES}         one     two     five
*** Test Cases ***
Logs Lists
    Log List    ${NUMBERS}

Log Scalar Variable
    Log    ${NUMBERS}[0]
```